# Is it possible to prevent simultaneous release for a release definition in TFS?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

At work, we use TFS as our release management service, and the release is triggered from the push of source code from git.

We need to prevent that a release starts if the previous one isn't fully finished (we have releases with multiple environments).

I have already tried in the deployment queue settings, to limit at one the parallel deployments, but this seems to work only for the single environment
(if that environment has finished the next release can start with that environment, but the old release is still running for other environments)

[image: Deployment queue settings]

Is it possible to achieve the behavior that I want with TFS? If so, how?